# Error while running jboss-cli command from Activiti workflow

Tags: activiti, jboss-cli

I am trying to run the command "./jboss-cli.sh --connect --file=test.cli" from Activiti service task to create a data source in JBoss dynamically. The command runs fine when running individually and creates a data source , but the following error comes when executing from workflow:

> FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)

No other errors are seen in JBoss server or CLI logs. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a full trace ?

Comment: This the only error statement I can see, nothing else :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding the below line in jboss-cli.sh

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8790,server=y,suspend=n"

Here address can be any port for debug mode.